# Populating an NSString with a null value

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, nsstring

In short, I need a string that contains null, rather than (null).

For example:

```
NSString *jsonRequest = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"{\"ename\":%@}", nil];
```

Forms a request that looks like:

```
{ "ename" : (null) }
```

But I need it to look like

```
{ "ename" : null }
```

Replacing nil with Nil, NULL, [NSNull null] all equate to the same output string.

Is there a way to accomplish this? The problem comes when I send my request to the server and it tries to parse it, but doesn't like the parenthesis around the null.

Comment: You'd be better off using a real JSON encoder than building it yourself. iOS 5 and later ships with one: [NSJSONSerialization](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSJSONSerialization_Class/).

Comment: Have you considered `stringWithFormat:@"\"ename\":null}"`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need special processing on the arguments to `stringWithFormat`:

```
NSString *ename = nil;
NSString *jsonRequest = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"{\"ename\":%@}",
                        ename != nil ? ename : @"null"];
```

Or create a macro:

```
#define STR_OR_NULL(x) (x) != nil ? (x) : @"null"

NSString *jsonRequest = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"{\"ename\":%@}", STR_OR_NULL(ename)];
```